# Force HTTPS for some pages and folders and HTTP for all others

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, redirect

I have in my `.htaccess` and I want to redirect `example.com/login`, `example.com/profile` and `example.com/form.php`
it works only for folder but doesn't work for pages.

Here is my `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# Force HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(login|profile|form\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(login|profile|form\.php) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]


# Force HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(login|profile|form\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule !^(login|profile|form\.php) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

So, if my user get in `http://example.com/login`, he is redirected to `https://example.com/login`. The same for profile page.

But, for single pages like `example.com/form.php`, it does not work

Please help me to write it in a correct way.

Comment: Why not keeping HTTPS everywhere? In a few months browsers will show HTTP connections as "insecure" so why not switch correctly? You gain security, and you remove your problem altogether.

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may use these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# Force HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(login|profile|form\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]


# Force HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(login|profile|form\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# more rules go below this line
```

Make sure to test this in an browser or clear browser cache completely.